# How to skip Email Verification from user registration process (Joomla)

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, registration

How can I skip the step that sending email to a new user for verification (in admin mode)?  I would like to trigger admin version of activation email to Joomla admin account. After admin clicks to activate link, new accounts got activated and users receive a confirmation email.

Answer (score 2):

Follow below procedure.

1. Go to Users->User Manage
2. Click on Options button on toolbar
3. Set "New User Account Activation" option to "Admin"
4. Enable "Notification Mail to Administrators" option (optional)

Please note that users still need to verify their email address, though activation will be done by admin.

Comment: is there any way to skip verify their email address?? many thanks